# Confused about C#/Silverlight workflow

Tags: silverlight

I'm working on some charting controls for my ASP.NET web app.

I am aware of visifire and the Silverlight charts MS now provides. My requirement came before I knew about these and their releases and I'm intending to write charts that are as good as Dundas or ChartFX (or is it SoftwareFX?).

Anyway, as the logic is the most logic-intensive part, I wrote some methods in a class. Things like "to plot the points, for each int in an int[], plot it on a chart at a specific co-ordinate (e.g. value 10 is 10 pixels up, etc)".

With an understanding of the logic, where does Silverlight come in?

Can I design the chart elements in XAML (I'm using KaXAML) and then how would I reference a C# method to plot the points?

In a nutshell, how do I refer to C# from XAML and vice versa? Can I build a Silverlight control with no C# logic and then implement it in my solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an out-of-the-box control that provides charting functionality such as the [Silverlight Control Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202&referringTitle=Home).  That is unless you need specific functionality that it does not provide.  In that case, you could still use the source as a starting point for the controls you want to create.